# Rotate window but not rotate desktop/screen

Tags: desktop, mate-desktop

I need to rotate a window (90º to the left) but with the desktop runs normal (without rotation).

The application is not mine and I have the source code. But I wonder about if there is a feature to do this action.

I remember the times of Compiz or Beryl that they have a lot of features to do awesome and unuseless things, but now I don't know if there are things left over from the past.

I am running a

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial

$ echo $XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP
MATE
```

Comment: Use [xnest](https://xfree86.org/4.2.0/Xnest.1.html) then rotate it.

Comment: I will try it. When I will have the answer, I will write it in this question.